# Generating Mesh of Rotated Graphics

Tags: graphics, finite-element-method, mesh, rotation

I have a simple geometry that consists of a few rotated rectangles

```
Graphics[Table[
  Rotate[Rectangle[{-(1/5), .55}, {1/5, .95}], x, {0, 0}], {x, π/
   8, 2 π, π/4}]]
```

[image]

I would like to convert this into a 2D boundary mesh. The standard workflow is the discretize the graphics elements then use `ToBoundaryMesh`. Or just put a `RegionUnion` straight into `ToBoundaryMesh`.

Here's what happens

```
DiscretizeGraphics[%]
(*EmptyRegion[2]*)
```

Here's a fun example that shows this issue in a bit of a simpler way

```
ToBoundaryMesh[Rectangle[]]
(*ElementMesh[{{0., 1.}, {0., 1.}}, Automatic]*)
```

```
ToBoundaryMesh[Rotate[Rectangle[], Pi/8]]
```

[image]

```
DiscretizeGraphics[Rectangle[]]
```

[image]

```
DiscretizeGraphics[Rotate[Rectangle[], Pi/8]]
```

[image]

So it seems that rotate only works when called inside `Graphics`? This seems to me like a bug unless im missing something. (I also tried `GeometricTransformation` with no luck)

My only terrible solution is this

```
(Graphics[
       Table[Rotate[Rectangle[{-(1/5), .55}, {1/5, .95}], 
         x, {0, 0}], {x, π/8, 2 π, π/4}]] // Rasterize // 
     ColorNegate // ImageMesh // ToBoundaryMesh)["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

Another thing I thought I'd mention is `RoundingRadius` gives some very strange results.

```
GraphicsRow[({Graphics[#1], DiscretizeGraphics[#1], 
     ToElementMesh[#1]["Wireframe"]} &)[
  Graphics[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, RoundingRadius -> .1]]]]
```

[image]

Or better yet, change the rectangle to default size

```
GraphicsRow[({Graphics[#1], DiscretizeGraphics[#1], 
     ToElementMesh[#1]["Wireframe"]} &)[
  Graphics[Rectangle[RoundingRadius -> .1]]]]
```

[image]

And while I'm talking about bugs. Has anyone else noticed that when you call `RandomPolyhedra` with no argumnents the UI gets mad but the code runs just fine.
[image]

Also the documentations indicates nothing about a default option.
[image]

I guess I hold Mathematica to too high a standard, but it's a shame when stiff doesn't work as expected.

Comment: According to the documentation for `Rotate`, it should be possible to use `Normal` to obtain a version of the graphics primitive where `Rotate` has been replaced by a version of the graphics primitive that is rotated. But for some reason, it doesn't work for rectangles.

Comment: `Graphics[Table[Rectangle[{-1/5,.55},{1/5,.95}]//RotationTransform[x,{0,0}],{x,π/8,2 π,π/4}]]//DiscretizeGraphics` works.

Answer (score 13):

As an alternative you can use `BoundaryElementMeshRotate` (and a few other Boolean operations) for boundary element meshes that are part of the [FEMAddOns](https://github.com/WolframResearch/FEMAddOns) paclet. The installation of the paclet is now very easy since the installation can be done via the [FEMAddOnsInstall](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/FEMAddOnsInstall) resource function.

Install and load the paclet:

```
ResourceFunction["FEMAddOnsInstall"][]
Needs["FEMAddOns`"]
(* Paclet[FEMAddOns, 1.3.2] *)
```

Now, generate the boundary mesh for the rectangle as usual.

```
bmesh1 = ToBoundaryMesh[Rectangle[{-(1/5), .55}, {1/5, .95}]];
```

And rotate it to your hart's content:

```
bms = Table[
   BoundaryElementMeshRotation[bmesh1, RotationMatrix[theta]], {theta,
     Pi/8, 2 Pi, Pi/4}];
```

You can put everything in a single boundary element mesh:

```
bm = BoundaryElementMeshJoin @@ bms;
bm["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

For more information on the BoundaryElementMesh-xyz functions please see the documentation of the paclet.

To mesh the geometry use:

```
ToElementMesh[bm]["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

If this is too fine on the boundary you can create a coarse boundary mesh and rotate that with:

```
bmesh1 = ToBoundaryMesh[Rectangle[{-(1/5), .55}, {1/5, .95}], 
   MaxCellMeasure -> Infinity];
```

Which will then lead too:

[image]

Answer (score 11):

I think the failure to discretize your first [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics) object is a bug.

But, instead of creating graphics objects and then converting them to [`MeshRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshRegion) objects with [`DiscretizeGraphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretizeGraphics), I think it is simpler to use [`Region`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Region) functionality instead, since [`Rectangle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rectangle) is already a [`Region`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Region) primitive. When working with [`Region`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Region) primitives you need to use [`TransformedRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedRegion) instead of [`GeometricTransformation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeometricTransformation) or [`Rotate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rotate). Then, to convert [`Region`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Region) primitives to [`MeshRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshRegion) objects, you need to use [`DiscretizeRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretizeRegion) or [`BoundaryDiscretizeRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoundaryDiscretizeRegion).

The following rotates a rectangle and converts it into a [`MeshRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshRegion) object:

```
BoundaryDiscretizeRegion @ TransformedRegion[Rectangle[], RotationTransform[Pi/8]]
```

[image]

You can create your desired `ElementMesh` output with:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
mesh = ToBoundaryMesh @ BoundaryDiscretizeRegion @ RegionUnion[
    Table[
        TransformedRegion[Rectangle[{-(1/5), .55}, {1/5, .95}], RotationTransform[θ]],
        {θ, Pi/8, 2Pi, Pi/4}
    ]
];
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much this works!

Comment: Another solution I  found is to discretize first then rotate. `DiscretizeGraphics@
 Table[Rotate[DiscretizeGraphics[Rectangle[{-1/6, 1/2}, {1/6, 1}]], 
   x, {0, 0}], {x, Pi/8, 2*Pi, Pi/4}]`